# chartjs radar glowing edges effect

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a simple radar chart using chart.js, and I'm trying to get the aesthetics similar to:

[image]

(Glowing edges by the borders)

To mimic this effect I tried using `createRadialgradient` and filling the data with that - but for the life of me could not find the center point of the graph in order to create the glow like effect - after thinking about it too, it wouldn't necessarily put the glowing at the borders of the lines, but rather the center of the graph...

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve something close using the following:

```
                            let draw = Chart.controllers.radar.prototype.draw;
                            Chart.controllers.radar.prototype.draw = function() {
                              let chart = this.chart;
                              let ctx = chart.ctx;
                              let _stroke = ctx.stroke;
                              ctx.stroke = function() {
                                ctx.save();
                                ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(3, 252, 240, 1)' //ctx.strokeStyle;
                                ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
                                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                                _stroke.apply(this, arguments);
                                ctx.restore();
                              };
                              draw.apply(this, arguments);
                              ctx.stroke = _stroke;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

for chartjs with line chart. I use this extension. https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-style

just follow the steps and then you will get it.